# Is there a way to use scripting methods in a saved view in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, view, google-bigquery

I am currently using a view in BigQuery to aggregate data from many different large tables. I then use this view to create a materialized flat table, with a MERGE statement to update it. However, the most recent LEFT JOIN I've added to the view caused the query that instantiates the materialized table to return the error: "Resources exceeded during query execution." The view right now is estimated to churn through 60GB of data.

To try to solve this issue, I tried using scripting to create temporary tables for the different subqueries in the view, thinking that this might save on resources. However, it appears that I am not able to save a view that uses scripting. Is there some way that this can be done?

Comment: Would it be possible to store the query in the view as a stored procedure and then call it to materialize or update the flat table?

Comment: Does this help? [Command and control now easier in BigQuery with scripting and stored procedures](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/command-and-control-now-easier-in-bigquery-with-scripting-and-stored-procedures)

Comment: what error you get when you try to save such a view?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant, the error reads: "Syntax error: Unexpected keyword CREATE at [3:1]"

Comment: share errors, share queries, share data... share what you need so people can actually answer your question

Comment: Could you post your query? Because this error is generally related to too much data for the number of workers that BigQuery assigned in you query. However, this can be caused for a variety of reasons, we need your query and more info about your data (sample data) to debug it.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that is not supported today. I had the errors weeks ago and I bet that is due to beta version.

For answering the comment, a very simple query

```
DECLARE dummy STRING;
set dummy="not work";
select dummy
```

This simply answers `not work`. Try to create a view from this, I have an error `Syntax error: Unexpected keyword DECLARE at [1:1]`. Not a data error, not a query error, simply not supported!

Using stored procedure not help because you use "script" command `CALL` for calling your stored procedure.

For information, there is a [feature request on this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147702260)